# Favorite recent post widget

Tags: plugins

Does anyone have a favorite widget for the sidebar that would show the last three posts with:

Title
Some of the content... read more

Answer (score 1):

You can create a widget ([Create a Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets)) like this:

```
<?php /*
Plugin Name: WDG
Plugin URI: 
Description: Plugin
Version: 0.1
Author URI: 
*/
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_wdg' );
function my_wdg() {
    register_widget( 'Wdg' );
}
class Wdg extends WP_Widget {
    function Wdg() {
            /* Settings of widget */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'Widget', 'description' => ' Plugin' );

        /* Control settings of widget */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'wdg' );

        /* Create widget */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'wdg', 'Wdg', $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    /* User-selected settings. */
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

    /* Before widget (theme defined). */
    echo $before_widget;

    /* Widget title (before e after theme defined). */
    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
             echo'     <div id="recent">
            <ul>';
             rewind_posts(); 
             query_posts('posts_per_page=3');
                     if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                        <li>
                         <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
                          <?php the_title();?>
                         </a></h5>
                         <span>
                          <?php the_excerpt ?>
                         </span>
                        </li>
                      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                      <p>I'm sorry</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
           <?php echo $after_widget; }
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    /* Strip tags modify qidget configuration. */
      $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    return $instance;
}

function form( $instance ) {

    /* default widget setting */
    $defaults = array(              
                    'title' =>  'Recent Comments',
        );
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
<?php
    } 
 }  ?>
```

This widget probably works!

Answer (score 0):

Query Posts widget.
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/15/query-posts-widget-wordpress-plugin